# Entity Framework Core CompileAsyncQuery syntax to do a query returning a list?

Tags: async-await, entity-framework-core

Documentation and examples online about compiled async queries are kinda sparse, so I might as well ask for guidance here.

Let's say I have a repository pattern method like this to query all entries in a table:

```cs
public async Task<List<ProgramSchedule>> GetAllProgramsScheduledList()
{
    using (var context = new MyDataContext(_dbOptions))
    {
        context.ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;
        return await context.ProgramsScheduledLists.ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

This works fine.

Now I want to do the same, but with an async [compiled query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/performance/advanced-performance-topics?tabs=with-di%2Cwith-constant#compiled-queries).

One way I managed to get it to compile is with this syntax:

```cs
static readonly Func<MyDataContext, Task<List<ProgramSchedule>>> GetAllProgramsScheduledListQuery;

static ProgramsScheduledListRepository()
{
    GetAllProgramsScheduledListQuery = EF.CompileAsyncQuery<MyDataContext, List<ProgramSchedule>>(t => t.ProgramsScheduledLists.ToList());
}

public async Task<List<ProgramSchedule>> GetAllProgramsScheduledList()
{
    using (var context = new MyDataContext(_dbOptions))
    {
        context.ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;
        return await GetAllProgramsScheduledListQuery(context);
    }
}
```

But then on runtime this exception get thrown:

```
System.ArgumentException: Expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Model.Scheduling.ProgramSchedule]' cannot be used for return type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Model.Scheduling.ProgramSchedule]]'
```

The weird part is that if I use any other operator (for example SingleOrDefault), it works fine. It only have problem returning List.

Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`EF.CompileAsync` for set of records, returns `IAsyncEnumrable<T>`. To get `List` from such query you have to enumerate `IAsyncEnumrable` and fill `List`,

```cs
private static Func<MyDataContext, IAsyncEnumerable<ProgramSchedule>> compiledQuery =
    EF.CompileAsyncQuery((MyDataContext ctx) =>
        ctx.ProgramsScheduledLists);

public static async Task<List<ProgramSchedule>> GetAllProgramsScheduledList(CancellationToken ct = default)
{
    using (var context = new MyDataContext(_dbOptions))
    {
        context.ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;

        var result = new List<ProgramSchedule>();
        await foreach (var s in compiledQuery(context).WithCancellation(ct))
        {
            result.Add(s);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I kinda expected this answer to be honest. But wouldn't that mean we have to do an extra iteration and list copy which is much heavier on memory and cpu time than the non-compiled ToListAsync() query? Or does it end up being the same?

Comment: Never mind, I found my answer here. It does enumerate it the same way:

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/690c20de4ab8bf97c4c1d4ca1fe01f7504a70a71/src/EFCore/Extensions/EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.cs#L2209

Comment: For anyone else reading this: The System.Linq.Async nuget package offer a ToListAsync() extension method for IAsyncEnumerable.